# On the derivation of mayers relation

Tags: thermodynamics

We write,

$$U=q+W$$ [first law]

for constant pressure case

$$ C_p \Delta T = \Delta q+ nR \Delta T $$

Now I do the same process but keep the evolume constant then

$$ U=C_V \Delta T= \Delta q$$

Now I put that in the original equation,

$$ C_p - C_v = nR$$

The doubt I have in this derivation is that couldn't the work change in constant volume process due to energy from $Vdp$?

And also know how did we know that that $ \Delta q$ is exactly $C_v \Delta T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no work in a constant volume. Draw a $PV$ diagram for constant volume case. As pressure grows there is no volume change, there is no area under $PV$ curve. It is similar to heating the metal container. Container "keeps" volume constant(until it blows up).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of mistakes in my original post. I have re-done the derivation correcting my mistakes.

Enthalpy is defined as:

$$ \Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta PV$$

For a constant pressure process,

$$\Delta H = nC_p \Delta T$$

$$ \Delta U = nC_v \Delta T$$

$$ \Delta (PV) = P \Delta V= nR \Delta T$$

Hence,

$$ nC_p \Delta T = nC_v \Delta T + nR \Delta T$$

$$ C_p - C_v = R$$

This basically relates to the energy change co-efficient of constant pressure and constant volume process. Also, there is no need for $Vdp$ work here as we had assumed an isobaric process from the start.

---

[Reference](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/specheat.html#:%7E:text=cp%20%3D%20cv%20%2B%20R,of%20physical%20systems%20and%20processes.)